# "base href" adds directory path in routing urls using ui-router

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, angular-ui-router, ui-sref, base-tag

**Summary :**

When using `<base href="/prod/public/" />` , it adds the directory path in routing urls **`e.x.`** `http://www.example.com/prod/public/home`

My angular app is hosted in the `prod/public` directory.

in my `public/index.html`:

```
<base href="/prod/public/" />
```

my routes are like :

```
$stateProvider
     .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: function($stateParams) {
          var path = 'app/users/views/home.html';
          return path;
      },
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
})
```

Directory structure :

```
public_html
      -.htaccess
      - other folders
      - prod
           - public
                - app
                - index.html
           - bower.json
           - .htaccess
           - package.json
           - gulpfile.js
           - Readme.md
```

**`.htaccess`** inside **`prod`** directory :

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ public/index.html [L]
```

and here is how I reference the state in the template :

```
<a ui-sref='home'>Go to home</a>
```

When click on this link it redirect to this url : `http://www.example.com/prod/public/home`

**Requirement :**

url should be **`http://www.example.com/home`** instead of **`http://www.example.com/prod/public/home`**

Comment: That's what [`base href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) is supposed to do. If you don't want it to do that, don't use it...?

Comment: why do you need to add base?

Comment: Are you using Angularjs' Html5Mode on? The hash is missing for the usual Angular routing behaviour.

Comment: @Boris yes i am using Html5Mode as true.

Comment: @Shreejibawa need to add base to provide the relative path to the assets of the application as i removed the hash tag from the urls

Comment: I'm not sure about your server configuration. If you are able to add virtual host in apache, then by setting document root to var/www/prod/public will do the job.

Comment: @JobinSKumar, I totally agree with you but my website is hosted on shared hosting, so i am having cpanel and when i login into ftp there is public_html folder where i put my code.

Comment: old thread. $location.absUrl() can be used to set the path. You can always append the /prod/public , if you know your routing structure. Not a great practice though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<base href="/prod/public/"/>` in angular routing is not to set the document root / Mask the url but to rather prepend urls with the defined url in HTML5 mode.

When you define a route eg `/home` angular will correctly set the URL as `/prod/public/home`.  If you wish to have your urls without that folder structure   then you will then need to put the files in the root directory (especially in the case of shared hosting) or alter the Nginix / Apache Document root setting to point to the correct path.  You can then set the  which will make your urls read as /home etc

Comment: I need your small suggestion on the directory structure that i am currently having. I updated the question with current directory structure of the application. Please suggest me the structure that i have to implement now to resolve this thing.